# 1GBのダミーファイルを作成するコマンドは？

Tags: linux, macos, shellscript

`1GB`の`dummy.iso`というファイルを作成したいです。

MacOS, Linux 環境で標準でインストールされているコマンドで巨大なダミーファイルを作成することは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Linux 限定ですが、比較的新し目の Linux カーネルと対応ファイルシステム(ext4,xfsなど)と util-linux パッケージがあるなら、`fallocate`(1) で一瞬で作成することができます。sparse file にはなりません。

以下の例では 1GB (1000000000バイト) のファイルを作ります:

```
$ fallocate -l 1gb dummy.iso
```

以下の例では 1GiB (1073741824バイト) のファイルを作ります:

```
$ fallocate -l 1gib dummy.iso
```

または:

```
$ fallocate -l 1g dummy.iso
```

なおシステムコール `fallocate`(2) に対応していない NFS ※などのファイルシステムでは失敗します:

```
$ fallocate -l 1g dummy.iso
fallocate: dummy.iso: fallocate が失敗: サポートされていない操作です
```

※ NFS 4.2 はサポートしているしているらしい。ただしオプション。

Answer (score 10):

yasuさんの回答でもありますが

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=dummy.iso bs=1G count=1
dd if=/dev/zero of=dummy.iso bs=1M count=1K
```

等とすることで全バイトが zero で埋め尽くされたファイルが作成できます。前者は実行に1GBのメモリーを必要とするため手元のマシンではエラーになりました orz
`/dev/zero`の他に`/dev/random`を使用して乱数で埋め尽くしたりもします。

BLUEPIXYさんの回答は少し異なります。

```
truncate --size=1G dummy.iso
```

こちらはファイルのサイズを見かけ上1GBに変更するものです。[Sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file)と呼ばれるもので実際にはディスク消費しません。ディスク使用量を表示する`du dummy.iso`を実行するとわかります。
`dd`コマンドでも

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=dummy.iso bs=1G skip=1 count=0
```

で同じ結果を得られます。

サイズ指定について、`dd`、`truncate`共に1K=1024、1KB=1000となります。

Answer (score 2):

[truncate](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_coreutils/man1/truncate.1.html) コマンドで

`truncate --size=1G dummy.iso`

Answer (score 1):

ddコマンドを利用します。

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=dummy.iso bs=100000 count=10000
```